# AWS not showing images on Django website deployed on heroku

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, heroku

I am trying to show my media files on a Django website hosted on Heroku via Amazon AWS S3. Currently, my settings for the AWS is:

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.environ.get('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.environ.get('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = os.environ.get('AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME')

AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = None
AWS_S3_OBJECT_PARAMETERS = {'CacheControl': 'max-age=86400',}
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'register.storage_backends.MediaStorage'
```

And in my storage_backends.py I have:

```
from storages.backends.s3boto3 import S3Boto3Storage

class MediaStorage(S3Boto3Storage):
    location = 'media'
    file_overwrite = False
```

When I open my website and inspect the images I can even the url seems to be correct:

```
https://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/media/defaults/user/default_u_i.png?AWSAccessKeyId=...
```

However, I still cannot see the image and it shows me the default thumbnail. What am I doing wrong here? I have uploaded the files to my bucket and I have checked multiple times and they are in the correct directory.

Thanks for all the help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I had to add my `REGION_NAME` set as well so I have added:

`AWS_S3_REGION_NAME = 'REGION_NAME'` to my settings as well.